# While loop in LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a confusion in the following code:

```
class ListNode:
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.data = x
      self.next = None

def hasCycle(self, head):
    if head is None or head.next is None:
      return False
    
    previous=set()
    while head.next is not None:
      if head.next in previous:
        return True
      previous.add(head.next)
      head=head.next    
    return False
```

In while loop `while head.next is not None:` why head.next is not None? Can we use instead just `while head is not None:` it gives the same result.

Comment: It's unnecessarily complex as written. A simple loop with `while head:` and testing if head is in previous else adding head to previous and updating head to head.next means you can remove the `if` clause entirely and make the while loop more comprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

It will give the same answer but the way the example code is written it will return the answer one node faster. It such a minor difference that it probably doesn't matter.

I believe that the code is written in this way because we are concerned if your LinkList is a cycle. We know it's a cycle because there is a repeat in the node values. Be checking head.next you're peeking into the future. If there is not a head.next it will return False. With your edit it will also return False but one loop later.

Comment: It also lets the entire loop be written in terms of two variables, `previous` and `head.next`, instead of three, which is slightly cleaner, style-wise.